# CakePHP - Tables with compound name in relationship HABTM

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

So... I have 2 tables:

```
banner_channel
banners
```

I need to create a table to relate the banners (table banners) with the channels of the banners (table banner_channel).

Obs.: I cant rename table **banner_channel** to **channel** only because I already have this table in database.

Maybe, the new table is:

```
banners_banner_channel
```

or

```
banners_channel
```

? I dont know.

Anyway, thanks.
*Sorry for my english... I'm brazilian 8D*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all according to the cakePHP naming conventions the table you named banner_channel should be in plurals: banner_channels

As for the naming, it should be:
banners_banner_channels

[CakePHP cheat sheat](http://www.bunkakikaku.jp/admin/upload/200706/pdf_20070626163140.pdf)

Comment: OP already said table cant be renamed, sometimes it needed to break conventions.

Comment: Yes. The table name is incorret, sorry. But, now I understand. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`banners_banner_channel` is the correct table name according to what you have already.

just have a look at all the options in the habtm relations as you will have to set them all manually. instead of just doing `'hasAndBelongsToMany' => array('BannerChannels')` you will need to set everything according to [this](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1044/hasAndBelongsToMany-HABTM)

first example: you will need atleast the following, `className`, `joinTable`, `foreignKey`, `associationForeignKey` and `with`

the rest you can tweak to your needs